# How to iterate through pandas data frame based off two list conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I created two unique lists, one that has all products and one that has all geographies. What I want to do is iterate through the data frame based on the values in both lists. I want to perform a calculation for the products within each geography. How would I setup the code to iterate through for when a product is sold at a specific geography it will perform the calculation then move onto the next? What I currently have is the code below but that only creates a data frame with one row.

```
# pseudo code:

# create unique lists:
DC_list = data4['Geography'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
Product_List = data4['Product'].drop_duplicates().tolist()


# create for loop and zip lists:
for p, g in zip(Product_List, DC_list):
    df_DC_product = (data4.loc[(data4["Geography"]==g) & (data4["Product"]==p)]).copy()
    # perform calculation
```

Comment: I've noticed that you've never accepted an answer, I kindly ask you to consider accepting answers once you are happy with them. If the question remains outstanding other users will use their precious time trying to help when the help might not be needed any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that copy is overwriting in every iteration, you'd better off by appending like this:

```
# pseudo code:

# create unique lists:
DC_list = data4['Geography'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
Product_List = data4['Product'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

df_DC_product=pd.DataFrame(columns=data4.columns)
# create for loop and zip lists:
for p, g in zip(Product_List, DC_list):
    df_DC_product = (data4.loc[(data4["Geography"]==g) & (data4["Product"]==p)]).append(df_DC_product)
    # perform calculation
```

please notice that I initialised the dataframe df_DC_product before the loop, and then replaced the copy by an append